# How can I see the original headers on an Email Message?

Tags: email, servicecloud

In my Email Message views, I can't find the "Click here to view original email headers" link described in the [Salesforce documentation](http://na7.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cases_email.htm).  How can I get it back?

[image]

(My org is on Summer '13.  I know I've found these links before, but I can't recall when I was last debugging email functionality or when I last saw the link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only view the email headers if they were saved when the email was received; doing so is the responsibility of your email handler (and will increase the storage space required for each email message).

## Using Email-to-Case:

Configuration for whether email headers are saved or discarded is set for each routing address.  To ensure that email headers are saved, go to Setup > Customize > Cases > Email-to-Case.  Click "Edit" next to your routing address(es).  Then, under "Email Settings," confirm that "Save Email Headers" is checked.

[image]

## Using Apex Email Services

If you want to save the headers from an incoming message, your Apex Email Service is responsible for copying the headers from the incoming `InboundEmail.headers` and saving them to an `EmailMessage.Headers` in the database.

## Using [Email2CasePremium](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC)

This is a 3rd-party app that enhances the functionality of SFDC's Email-to-Case.  To save email headers, go to All Tabs > Email to Case Premium Settings > Inbound Configuration.  Confirm that "Save Inbound Email Headers" is selected.

[image]